# Select a webpack configuration when webpack.config file is exporting multiple configs

Tags: webpack

A `webpack.config.js` file like this can export multiple configs:

```
module.exports = [{entry: 'a.js'}, {entry: 'b.js'}];
```

How do I select one of the configs from CLI when I invoke webpack?

Answer (score 4):

In Webpack 3.2 you can provide a config name with `--config-name` flag. Your configs should have a name property.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting one config out of an array from CLI is currently not possible. Your best bet is to create two extra config files (each of them referencing one of the two configs in your main file) and point webpack to that configuration instead.

Example:

`webpack.a.config.js`

```
var allConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
module.exports = allConfig[0];
```

And then call Webpack with `--config webpack.a.config.js`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that approach. I was partially looking for multi-config webpack.config.js files. I opened an issue for webpack:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2821

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
// webpack.config.js

export default [
  webpackConfig1,
  webpackConfig2,
]

function webpackConfig1(){
  return {
    name: "main",
    entry: ["main.js"],
  }
}


function webpackConfig2(){
  return {
    name: "other",
    entry: ["other.js"],
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
webpack // compiles both configs
webpack --config-name main // only with name=main
webpack --config-name other // only with name=other
```